# Why did it crash?

Tags: computer-puzzle

You are on your computer on June 23rd, 2021 at 10:24:58 am, when it suddenly becomes bricked. Your electronic devices all fail, except for your newest technology. Why?

Hint 1:

> Look at the year and the time passed since it began.

Hint 2:

> T1J11 >ks

*This didn't happen to me, this is just a scenario I made up myself. It could've possibly happened in real life.*

Comment: Does it have something to do with a Y2K/year 2038-esque problem?

Comment: Most computers use Unix time, which is a 32 bit integer that keeps track of the seconds since Jan 1, 1970. This could potentially have to do with using less than 32 bits.

Comment: @TylerSelden "most computers" Don't 64 bit computers use 64 bit integers to keep track of time?

Comment: @newQOpenWid Yes.

Comment: @TylerSelden rot13(Lbh’er pybfr.)

Comment: in Unix time, this is ``(1624443898) in base 10 = (01100000110100110000101111111010) in base 2``.

Comment: @newQOpenWid It is instead 1624458298.  (You used 6am instead of 10am.)

Comment: I suspect the fails may have been caused by bit flips from rogue electrons from outer space. Bit flips happened to occur in all devices with static RAM, while newest devices with dynamic RAM carried on. However, I cannot find a way to connect the specified date and time and my hypothesis.

Comment: @webadventurer It is likely nothing related with the outside world and is probably a complete result of the way the computer measures time or some other thing.

Comment: @newQOpenWid yes

Comment: Mcaffe antivirus' crash routine triggered by it's creator's suicide?

Comment: @IuriGuilherme No.

Comment: @RobPratt I think newQOpenWid's calculation is correct (for GMT/UTC). Are you applying a timezone offset?

Comment: @fljx Yes, it seems so.  I guess there is some ambiguity about where "your computer" is.

Comment: Any more hints? Is it related to the binary representation of the time or some other base, is the computer using Unix time, and so on. And most importantly, **How can an overflow of time crash a computer**? Most of us are just left randomly guessing as to the properties of the specific date and time you put right now.

Comment: C float32 imprecision starts to show at unix timestamp 16777219 which is as soon as July 14th, 1970 04:20:19 am. Nearest precise float32 values to the given date can be found at 1624443968 (June 23th, 2021 10:26:08) and 1624443839 (June 23th, 2021 10:23:59) tested with CPython `sys.float_info(max=1.7976931348623157e+308, max_exp=1024, max_10_exp=308, min=2.2250738585072014e-308, min_exp=-1021, min_10_exp=-307, dig=15, mant_dig=53, epsilon=2.220446049250313e-16, radix=2, rounds=1)`. Current implementation only gets weird at January 1st, 3000.

Comment: Hmm? Well, the distance in time is `111001001010010111111010 (base 2) == 14984698 (base 10)`. Should we look in binary or decimal?

Comment: rot13(Ybbx va qrpvzny) @newQOpenWid

Comment: I think I have an idea where this is going, but according to my calculations the tipping point would be 23.06.2021 07:34:03 UTC. Is there some weird timezone stuff going on?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Consider that the integer used for storing the date time value

> may be a 32-bit signed integer, i.e has a max value of `2147483647`

Notice that

> The max value 1) starts with `21` and 2) if the rest is to be regarded as a percentage (47.483647%), it looks as if it could match with how much of the year 2021 has passed on June 23rd.

Let the imaginary date time format be an integer which is constructed like

> (last 2 digits of year) **+concat+** (how much of the year has passed as a percentage, 8 digits + remove decimal point)
> i.e.
>  `((Year - 2000) * 10^8) + floor(SecondsPassed / AverageSecondsInAYear * 10^8)`

Let's try to calculate that max value as an actual date

> Calculate `(0.47483647 * 365.25 * 24 * 60 * 60)` (note the average 365.25 is taken thanks to @fljx in the comments), add that to `2021.01.01 00:00:00` and it yields: `2021.06.23 10:24:59 UTC`

OP here. The newest technology is

> 64-bit.

Comment: If you use the actual length of a year (just under 365.25 days) I think this gets much closer.

Answer (score 2):

My wild guess:

> A solar flare or another cataclysm that would be able to disable electronics worldwide for a certain amount of time *could have possibly* happened. Your "newest technology" is a tool you made recently that doesn't use electricity (for example a hammer or axe).

Comment: Well, this isn’t the answer, sadly. Look at the tag.